# "Smart commenting" in LaTeX

Tags: viewers, comments, ocg

Is there any package that lets me insert "smart comments" in a LaTeX document?

What I mean by "smart commenting":

I have a source (.tex) file of notes of the lecture that happened in the classroom. However, the notes do not have the detailed discussion of the proofs. I want to edit the source file and add the comments, such that the output PDF file will be same as the output of the original source; except that it will have small buttons (or similar constructs), which on pressing, will reveal the additional comments that I have made.

Essentially, one could achieve this by adding editor notes using any of the PDF reading programs. However, those notes are not portable from program-to-program, and more importantly, I cannot insert mathematical equations using those annotation tools, which I can using LaTeX.

I know this sounds kind of vague, but can someone help?

Comment: Have you tried [fixme](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixme)? It has many different ways to show the todos.

Comment: I have not. But I cannot find a working example on the page you linked to decide whether that is what I want. Can you link to an actual document that uses fixme notes?

Comment: What I did not get from your request: You have slides in the lecture, right? And there is a notes file for each lecture. The slides have the detailed proofs, the notes not?
For the beamer package one can create a combined file, which generates notes and slides in one document. I once created a German article in my blog: http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=1053

Comment: What you could do as well is to use the `attachfile`package to attach additional PDF files to the main file. I use this feature to add the TeX code of my documents to the PDF container file to have source and result in one file.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear. I have a source .tex file of notes, which has very rough discussions of proofs. I want to edit the same source file to add my own notes, which will be embedded in the original document; but won't modify the overall structure of the document. So, for example, I'd like to view my own notes on a click on a small button next to a line that needs more explanation.

Comment: @taninamdar Unfortunately it seems that `fixme` doesn't handle math well. If that is a constraint because it uses pdf comments, I don't know. It may be because it uses the `pdfcomment` package.

Comment: @taninamdar All solutions using additional content (ocg, pdf comments) or JavaScript will not be very portable. So you probably won't find a solution which works in many viewers, simply because most don't support the more advanced pdf features.

Comment: You might be able to approximate what you want using the `answers` package to write the proofs next to the theorems with but have them appear at the end of the document. A `hyperref` link would take you from the theorem to the proof. I have done this with hints for exercises.

Comment: Isn't pdfcomment what you want?

Answer (score 4):

You could use *ocg* and use different layers for the main document and the proofs, although this solution might not be particularly user-friendly.

One example using ocgx:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ocgx}
\begin{document}
It is common knowledge that $1+1=1$. \switchocg{ocg1}{[PROOF]}

\begin{ocg}{OCG 1}{ocg1}{0}
Proof: I am one. The Pope is one. Therefore, the Pope and I are one.
\end{ocg}
\end{document}
```

Please note that most PDF viewers can’t handle OCG correctly.

Comment: Yes but can you expand your answer with an example? It is not particularly useful to point to a very generic concept. Also one important detail is that it would only work with Acrobat.

Comment: Yeah, I would like to see a working example before deciding whether I should implement it. :-)

Comment: I provided a somewhat minimal example. There are more sophisticated ways to use OCG in LaTeX though.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like `pdfcomment` may be what you're looking for.  Like all the more advanced pdf features, it doesn't work with all pdf viewers; xpdf will display the comment icon but can't seem to get to the comment itself, while okular can handle them correctly.  I didn't check on anything else.  Run `texdoc pdfcomment` with your preferred viewer; the second page of the documentation has a test which will tell you whether it works.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
Now is the time for all good men\pdfcomment{And women.} to
come to the aid of their party.
\end{document}
```

There are lots of options---you can put the comment in the margin, you can use different graphics to indicate a comment's presence, you can compile with the comment and with *replies* to the comments, and so forth---but at its root it's simple as can be, as you can see above.

If you really need fully typeset LaTeX math, though, you're probably going to have to use OCG or something similar, as I don't think you can get complex equations in pdf comments.  You'd be stuck doing a plain-text substitute, as far as I can tell.